# Custom collision function with mesh class not outputting vector

Tags: c++, math, 3d, geometry

I am working on a custom 3D renderer engine based on Javidx9 3D engine tutorial. I'm trying to get some collision detection with rays and segments and it's not properly working.

I've tried implementing different methods trying to make it work the way I want it to but either the function is not working or its the way im using the function after it has been implemented. The current algorithm I am using is based on ["Real-Time Collision Detection", by Christer Ericson, Pg 191](https://books.google.com/books?id=WGpL6Sk9qNAC&pg=PA188&lpg=PA188&dq=test+if+3d+triangle+intersects+with+3d+segment+c%2B%2B&source=bl&ots=Po3TpN6bhN&sig=ACfU3U3HxfBjCqRCZpor-d7chIP77lngyA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiUxO-Hu8LkAhXEIjQIHaaJCiYQ6AEwB3oECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q&f=false). However, when the program is run I am getting no triangles intercepted triangles (the return vector is always zero). Is there something wrong with my code?

Note: I have some predefined functions that are self-explanatory based on the name.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <strstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

#define SMALL_NUM   0.00000001                                                          // anything that avoids division overflow

using namespace std;

// Created a 2D structure to hold texture coordinates
struct vec2d
{
    float u = 0;
    float v = 0;
    float w = 1;
};

struct vec3d
{
    float x = 0;
    float y = 0;
    float z = 0;
    float w = 1; // Need a 4th term to perform sensible matrix vector multiplication

    bool operator==(vec3d a) const
    {
        if (a.x == x && a.y == y && a.z == z && a.w == w)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    vec3d operator+(const vec3d& a) const
    {
        return vec3d{ a.x + x, a.y + y, a.z + z, w };
    }

    vec3d operator-(const vec3d& a) const
    {
        return vec3d{ a.x - x, a.y - y, a.z - z, w };
    }

    vec3d operator*(const vec3d& a) const
    {
        return vec3d{ a.x * x, a.y * y, a.z * z, w };
    }

    vec3d operator/(const vec3d& a) const
    {
        return vec3d{ a.x / x, a.y / y, a.z / z, w };
    }

    vec3d operator+(const float& a) const
    {
        return vec3d{ a + x, a + y, a + z, w };
    }

    vec3d operator-(const float& a) const
    {
        return vec3d{ a - x, a - y, a - z, w };
    }

    vec3d operator*(const float& a) const
    {
        return vec3d{ a * x, a * y, a * z, w };
    }

    vec3d operator/(const float& a) const
    {
        return vec3d{ a / x, a / y, a / z, w };
    }
};

struct triangle
{
    vec3d p[3];
    vec2d t[3]; // added a texture coord per vertex
    int triid = 0;
    wchar_t sym;
    short col;
    bool calculated = false;
};

struct mesh
{
    vector<triangle> tris;
};

struct collision
{
    bool plane = false;
    triangle tris;
    vec3d points;
};

float Vector_DotProduct(vec3d v1, vec3d v2)
{
    return v1.x * v2.x + v1.y * v2.y + v1.z * v2.z;
}

float Vector_Length(vec3d v)
{
    return sqrtf(Vector_DotProduct(v, v));
}

vec3d Vector_Normalise(vec3d v)
{
    float l = Vector_Length(v);
    return { v.x / l, v.y / l, v.z / l };
}

vec3d Vector_CrossProduct(vec3d v1, vec3d v2)
{
    vec3d v;
    v.x = v1.y * v2.z - v1.z * v2.y;
    v.y = v1.z * v2.x - v1.x * v2.z;
    v.z = v1.x * v2.y - v1.y * v2.x;
    return v;
}

vector<collision> CollisionSegment(vec3d ray, vec3d rayend, mesh* m)
{
    vector<collision> ret;                                                              // The return varaible
    vec3d raydir = Vector_Normalise(rayend - ray);                                      // The ray direction

    for (auto tri : m->tris)
    {
        vec3d ab = tri.p[1] - tri.p[0];
        vec3d ac = tri.p[2] - tri.p[0];
        vec3d qp = rayend - ray;

        vec3d n = Vector_CrossProduct(ab, ac);

        float d = Vector_DotProduct(qp, n);
        if (d <= SMALL_NUM)             continue;

        vec3d ap = ray - tri.p[0];
        float t = Vector_DotProduct(ap, n);

        if (t < SMALL_NUM)              continue;
        if (t < d)                      continue;

        vec3d e = Vector_CrossProduct(qp, ap);
        float v = Vector_DotProduct(ac, e);

        if (v < SMALL_NUM || v > d)     continue;
        float w = -Vector_DotProduct(ab, e);

        if (w < SMALL_NUM || v + w > d) continue;

        float ood = 1.0f / d;
        t *= ood;
        v *= ood;
        w *= ood;
        float u = 1.0f - v - w;

        ret.push_back(collision{ false, tri, vec3d() });
    }

    return ret;
}

int main()
{
    mesh meshCube;
    meshCube.tris = {

        // SOUTH
        { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,    0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,    1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,     0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,       0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,       1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,},
        { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,    1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,    1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,     0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,       1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,       1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,},

        // EAST                                                                                        
        { 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,    1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,    1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,     0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,       0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,       1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,},
        { 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,    1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,    1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,     0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,       1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,       1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,},

        // NORTH                                                                                       
        { 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,    1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,    0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,     0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,       0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,       1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,},
        { 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,    0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,    0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,     0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,       1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,       1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,},

        // WEST                                                                                        
        { 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,    0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,    0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,     0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,       0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,       1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,},
        { 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,    0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,    0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,     0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,       1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,       1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,},

        // TOP                                                                                         
        { 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,    0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,    1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,     0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,       0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,       1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,},
        { 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,    1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,    1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,     0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,       1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,       1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,},

        // BOTTOM                                                                                     
        { 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,    0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,    0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,     0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,       0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,       1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,},
        { 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,    0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,    1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,     0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,       1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,       1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,},

    };

    vec3d p1 = { -1.5f, -1.5f, -1.5f };
    vec3d p2 = { 1.5f, 1.5f, 1.5f };

    vector<collision> hits = CollisionSegment(p1, p2, &meshCube);

    return 0;
}
```

What I want is whenever I look at a mesh I want a vector of the triangles that come between me and my camera segment.

Comment: The code fails to compile.   Please post a [mcve].

Comment: @ PaulMcKenzie alrighty give me a second

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie the code is now executable

Comment: Well, the obvious reason for the error is that your code never gets to the `ret.push_back(` line, all due to the conditions above that causes the `continue`'s to be executed.  Why that is -- you need to debug your application.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie According to the book, the code example displayed for intersecting triangles and segments only deals with one triangle. The function returns if the ray is outside the triangle. I need to handle multiple triangles so I created a for loop to go though the mesh structure. Where the code *continue;*s the function says the triangle doesent intersect and moves onto the next. As far as I can tell there the same idea from the book.